# dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold command --data-annotations or -d command line parameter doesn't seem to work

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, scaffolding

I have a simple database with one table, that has various properties.

I am using the latest .NET core 6 with the latest EF (6.0.4)

I wanted to scaffold my database so it generates models, so I run the command:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=MyServerName;Database=MyDBName;User Id=sa;Password=abc123;" 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Model --no-pluralize -d -f
```

the -d command is supposed to use data annotations rather than fluent annotation, however it does not. I end up with a `MyTable` class, with the properties listed plainly, e.g. `public int MyTableId; public string MyTableProperty;....` and then in my `MyDBNameContext` class `OnModelCreating` method, several pages of stuff like this:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasIndex(e => e.SomeColumn, "idx_somecolumn");

                entity.Property(e => e.firstcolumn)
                    .HasColumnType("decimal(8, 1)")
                    .HasColumnName("FirstColumn");

                ...
```

This is pretty hideous.  The help states this:

> -d|--data-annotations                  Use attributes to configure
> the model (where possible). If omitted, only the fluent API is used.

I could painstakingly go through manually and add the annotations but then if I regenerate in the future due to changes, then it will undo my work.

Is there a reason why the data annotations attribute is not working?

Comment: Have a look at EF  Core Power Tools

Comment: Use the long form of the parameter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't delete my question so I'll just post the answer here...

It's a bug!

`-d` is not working, but `--data-annotations` is working.

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26687

Comment: I had same issue and now it fixed for me too :) Thank you for sharing @vahid-tajari NibblyPig

Comment: Update: -DataAnnotations
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold 
"Server=MyServerName;Database=MyDBName;User Id=sa;Password=abc123;" 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Model --no-pluralize --data-annotations -f
```