# Reverse Engineering DB model doesnt produce Data Annotations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework Core (7.07)

I have a database and run the following commands in a new project against this DB:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef (Installs version 7.07)

mkdir EFCoreScaffoldexample

cd EFCoreScaffoldExample

dotnet new console

dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=.\;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Model -d
```

for the last line (especially the param `-d`) it is supposed to produce the code such as

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

but instead i get

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Is there a command or parameter im missing?

Comment: See the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72208253/5509738) and see [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26687#issuecomment-970776565)